# Getting javascript array through jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

maybe you could help me.

My jquery ajax call result is splitted with "||" and it creates an array of values. One of these values is a string like this:

```
[['2012-11-18', 33, 2], ['2012-11-19', 162, 11], ['2012-11-20', 140, 13]]
```

I need to make this as a viable javascript array to pass it to google chart drawchart(myarray) function to use it with data.addRows(myarray);

Can anyone help me to achieve it?

I can make this ajax returned array to look like whatever, what is important is that i could use this array to update google chart.

OKay, heres my ajax success code:

```
success: function(response)
     {
        response_d = response.split("||");
        response_message = response_d[0];

        if(response_message == 'ok') {
           $("#contr_count").html(response_d[1]); 
           $("#contr_average").html(contr_time(response_d[2])); 
           $("#contr_space_average").html(contr_time(response_d[3]));
           var chartdata = $.parseJSON(response_d[4]);
           drawChart(chartdata);
           $("#contr_list").html(response_d[5]); 
        }
        else {

        }
     }
```

And here is the drawchart function

```
function drawChart(chartdata) {
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Minutit tagasi');
  data.addColumn('number', 'T pikkus');
  data.addColumn('number', 'T vahe pikkus');

  data.addRows(chartdata);

data.addRows(dateArray);
 var options = {
   title:                 'T pikkuse ja vahe graafik (viimane 60 min)',
   backgroundColor:          '#fdf3e9', 
   colors:                ['#FF7F00','#437C17'],
   curveType:             'function',
   enableInteractivity:      true, 
   legend:                {position: 'bottom'},
   vAxis:                 {direction: -1},
   hAxis:                 {direction: -1},
   chartArea:             {width: '85%'}
 };

 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('contr_graph'));
 chart.draw(data, options);
```

}

The code gives json error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character" ar firebug.

Comment: its an array of arrays. better make it an array of objects...

Comment: OKay, i added the code. Maybe you can help me now :)

Comment: Try replacing the single quotes with double quotes. Your array should be `[["2012-11-18", 33, 2], ["2012-11-19", 162, 11], ["2012-11-20", 140, 13]]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `'` with `"` first.
Try with:

```
var s = "[['2012-11-18', 33, 2], ['2012-11-19', 162, 11], ['2012-11-20', 140, 13]]";
var arr = $.parseJSON(s.replace(/'/g,'"'))
```

[Here a jsfiddle with a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xYMpm/).
Open the  javascript console to see the results.