# converting an ajax returned string to an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, parsing

I have an AJAX call which returns a `string` which ideally should be an array of arrays

```
var jsonString = "[['name1', 30, 20], ['name2', 10, 100], ['name3', 140, 130]]";
```

This is what I get returned. I would like to convert it to an array of arrays

```
var jsonArray = [['name1', 30, 20], ['name2', 10, 100], ['name3', 140, 130]];
```

Obviously `string.split(",")` wont work and gives me an array with 9 elements.

How do I parse this?

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/hgLJh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

naveen I checked your string and if you are sure your string have ' instead of " in array elements, you can replace them with " and then you can just parse them as json:

```
JSON.parse('[["name1", 30, 20], ["name2", 10, 100], ["name3", 140, 130]]');
```

returns array of arrays.

Regards.

Comment: cool. i could just do a string.replace and make it work. oh the nuances of javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function:

```
var jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Though note that this will only work if the string you're passing to it is valid JSON. What you've provided isn't - JSON strings are wrapped in double-quotes, not single.

Comment: you are just repeating what i have written in my fiddle. :)

Comment: Yep, invalid JSON. Well spot!

Comment: @naveen - Your fiddle suggests that you are using jQuery and that you already know the answer. What's the point of asking?

Comment: @naveen I didn't even notice that there *was* a jsFiddle, I stopped reading as soon as I'd seen enough to know the answer to the question. You need to use JSON.parse() and provide valid JSON; if you knew the first part, the second is where you're going wrong.

Comment: guys... i dont know the answer. i am getting such a string from my ajax call. i want my javascript to recognize it as a array of arrays..

Comment: to clarify, i am trying to learn something from a question asked at SO. I would like to know what happens if one passes an array of array as a string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135413/getting-javascript-array-through-jquery-ajax

Comment: @naveen Your fiddle does not contain AJAX. jQuery decodes JSON from AJAX automatically!

Comment: @naveen You'll need to change the server-side code handling the AJAX call to return valid JSON, because what you're currently getting returned is invalid and therefore unusable. [JSON](http://json.org) is the format for representing JavaScript objects (and arrays) as strings, but it has a very strict specification that you have to meet.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Thats because it was a part of a complex question that could be abstracted to this simple issue. Here is the fiddle if you want to see it. http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/LBkyF/ and for the last time, the string is NOT JSON. forget JSON."There is no spoon".

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: I understand. I am asking if such a scenario occurs, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @naveen Not that I can think of off hand. This is precisely what JSON is intended for, not using it just makes everything much, much more complicated. You could try replacing the necessary characters to make your string valid JSON, then parsing that, but there are so many cases you'd have to handle it would probably be more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: @naveen - Well, sorry. The `json` prefix in your variables misguided everyone.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: sorry about that pal :)

Answer (score 1):

With this string you could use: `JSON.parse(jsonString.replace(/'/g,'"'))`.